What is the difference between TreeCache (Infinispan Tree Cache) and JVMCache?
We have cache implementation in our project and we have been using Infinispan TreeCache. However, after wildfly upgrade from 10 - 26, we are facing issues with respect to TreeCache as it has been deprecated.
We are trying to find alternatives for the TreeCache.
For complete understanding, I want to know the difference between TreeCache and JVMCache.
I have tried to modify Infinispan Cache but it doesn't accept other parameters besides the key, value pair. However, the requirement is to pass 3 parameters, String, Object, Object (cacheType, key, value) -> cacheType being the source of the cache process for that instance.
Looking for alternatives in Infinispan.
